# Another static vs non static methods

Tags: android, static

I followed the example from [this](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-to-fix-cannot-make-a-static-reference-to-the-non-static-method) site to eliminate the issues with static vs non static methods.

```
public static void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {
  Log.d("Buttons","Start voice called in buttons");         

  Buttons demo = new Buttons();
  Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
  intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
  intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Voice recognition Demo...");

  Log.d("Buttons","Intent to start the command is:  "  +intent);
  demo.startActivityForResult(intent,VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);           
}
```

This code works in the main activity but the `demo.startActivityForResult(intent,VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);` generates the following error in the "Buttons" service class:

> The method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) is undefined for the type Buttons

Can anyone clue me into what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You're calling a method on Buttons that doesn't exist?

Comment: @DaveNewton the name of the class is Buttons

Comment: Okay. There's no method taking the arguments you're passing, though.

Comment: @DaveNewton    That's what I thought.  What can I do to call startVoiceRecognitionActivity() from a non static method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't really answer this without knowing more about the Buttons class... Is Buttons an Activity or does it otherwise have a Context? If not, there's your problem. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848775/use-startactivityforresult-from-non-activity).

Comment: The original problem started with this thread: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832635/android-service-to-start-activity-not-reacting-like-i-think-it-should).  I couldn't get the activity to start like I need it to.  So I thought I would create a service to enable calling the methods while the main activity is not shown on the display.  Is my thought process logical?